# Systemd is really slow in comparison to upstart

Tags: boot, upstart

I have been using Ubuntu for a long time now, this is what happened when I use:

**Systemd:**
It performs really bad using `systemd`: it uses 95% of the CPU all the time and the PC gets really hot. Also it takes a really long time to boot (about 1.5 min, and sometimes it does not boot at all as it has a black screen at boot.)

**Upstart:**
When I tried the `upstart` options at boot, it performs as expected, booted in seconds, and it was awesome as it should be.

**Laptop:**

- AMD A8
- Radeon
- SSD

**Questions:**

1. Why does upstart perform better than `systemd`?
2. How can I debug `systemd`?
3. Should I switch to upstart? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/  Please visit the [Ask Ubuntu Tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) to better understand how this site works, as it is quite different from a forum...

Comment: @Fabby I updated my post, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

## 1- Why:

Upstart's model for starting processes is `greedy event-based`, all available jobs whose startup events happen are started as early as possible. During boot, `upstart` synthesizes some initial events like startup or rcS as the tree root, the early services start on those, and later services start when the former are running.

Systemd's model for starting processes is `lazy dependency-based`, a unit will only start if and when some other starting unit depends on it. During boot, `systemd` starts a root unit, which then transitively expands and starts its dependencies.

## 2- systemd-debug-generator

Is a generator that reads the kernel command line and understands three options:

```
systemd.mask= option
```

Followed by a unit name,this unit is masked for the runtime. This is useful to boot with certain  units removed from the initial boot transaction for debugging system startup.

```
systemd.wants= option
```

Followed by a unit name, this unit is added to the initial transaction.    This is useful to start one or more additional units at boot.

```
systemd.debug-shell option
```

The debug shell service "debug-shell.service" is pulled into the boot transaction. It will spawn a debug shell on tty9 during early system startup.

## 3- To do so:

Select the `Advanced options for Ubuntu` at the boot prompt when your computer starts.

Then, select the `Ubuntu, with Linux ... (upstart)` entry.

*However, this will work only for the current session*

So if you want to make it permanent, you'll have to install the `upstart-sysv` package.

## [Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers)

Comment: Thanks. Any detailed example on how it can be used to speed-up boot on a default installation?

Comment: Go to: https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/systemd/Optimizations/